# Only coloring one name PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Basically i am making a userlist where it displays username, and the username is styled according to what group they are in.

I got a groups table (g_id, g_title, color, style)

This is my code:

```
<?php
$result = $db->query("
SELECT u.id
     , u.username
     , u.email
     , u.banned
     , u.group_id
     , g.g_id
     , g.color
     , g.style 
  FROM groups AS g 
  LEFT 
  JOIN users AS u 
    ON u.id=g.g_id
    ");

                foreach($result44 as $item): 

                ?>

                <tr>

                    <td class="tc3"><?php echo $item['id'] ?></td>
                    <td class="tc3"><a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $item['id'] ?>"><span style="color: <?php echo $item['color'] ?>; font-weight: <?php echo $item['style'] ?>"><?php echo $item['username']?></span></a></td>
```

The issue is that it only colors 1 name, the first name and its mine but my other admin doesnt have a color? Any idea... im new to this with joining tables and need some tips/help.

Yes i am aware that i am vulnerable to SQL injections and i am going to be swapping out to prepared statements after i figure this out! So if anyone has any idea why it's doing this please help me out..

Regards.

EDIT:

I changed ON u.id=g.g_id to ON u.group_id=g.g_id, but there is still a problem and its outputting 2 extra rows in the userlist for no reason?

FIXED it by doing:

```
SELECT u.id
     , u.username
     , u.email
     , u.banned
     , u.group_id
     , g.g_id
     , g.color
     , g.style 
  FROM groups AS g 
  LEFT 
  JOIN users AS u 
    ON u.group_id=g.g_id 
 WHERE 
 WHERE u.group_id=g.g_id
```

Comment: if you could print out the values in the database, that would be helpful.

Comment: Also provided the generated HTML output.

Comment: There is no vulnerability here. And that isn't your fix.

Answer (score 0):

Select from Users then left join Groups.

```
u.group_id = g.g_id
```